# How to optimize the downloading of data to the server in SSIS

Tags: sql, ssis

Good day.
Need to get records from an Oracle database to a database in SQL Server. The data source type (ODBC) the performed using a SQL command, where I am taking all possible indices according to my requirement. The process runs fine, the problem is that it takes a long time and I need to be something quick. The process can not be performed with lookup, requires merge or merge join, simply load a table from Oracle to SQL under certain conditions.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Which part of it is causing it to be slow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check what is your limiting factor. Generally there are 3 points to check:

1. Remote server is slow.
   Source DB can run low on memory, read speed or free CPU. Substitute you query with a straight `SELECT` statement with no `WHERE` clause or `JOIN`s and see if your SSIS package runs faster.
2. Target DB. 
   You may have indexes enabled, high write latency on HDD or not enough CPU.
   Run an `INSERT` for your target table and see how longer it takes.
3. Problem may be in the middle: transfer between 2 servers. Network usually is main bottleneck. Is SSIS hosted on the same server as SQL server? then you have 2 network connections + possible hardware bottleneck on dedicated SSIS machine.

Depending on the bottleneck there are different solutions.

If you have network capacity and bottleneck is 1 CPU per query on Oracle, then you can partition your data horisontally (IDs 1 to 100, 101 to 200 etc); establish multiple connections to Oracle and load data in several streams. Number of streams is 1 less then number of CPUs on Oracle, SSIS or SQL Server (which ever is smaller).

Comment: The servers both Oracle and SQL are on different computers. my computer has the necessary capacity and the SQL command filtré best, including indice.   Thanks!

Comment: If I read your comment as both servers and your computer are not running at max capacity on at least 1 resource (IO, RAM, CPU thread - not total CPU!), then your network is the bottleneck. There default limitations in SSIS package for a batch size. Check them. If you want to make it faster - you need to find bottleneck.